# Multiple Pages Web Scraping with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, pandas, loops, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to write a code to scrape some date from pages about hotels. The final information (name of the hotel and address) should be export to csv. The code works but only on one page...

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # HTML data structure

page_url = requests.get('https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_url.content, 'html.parser')

list = soup.find(id='nav-lista-obiektow')
items = list.find_all(class_='et-list__details flex-grow-1 d-flex d-md-block flex-column')

nazwa_noclegu = [item.find(class_='h3 et-list__details__name').get_text() for item in items]
adres_noclegu = [item.find(class_='et-list__city').get_text() for item in items]

dane = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'nazwa' : nazwa_noclegu,
        'adres' : adres_noclegu
    }
)

print(dane)

dane.to_csv('noclegi.csv')
```

I tried a loop but doesn't work:

```
for i in range(22):
    url = requests.get('https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/'.format(i+1)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you check url for other pages? It is different then you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urls are different then you use - you forgot `?page=`.

And you have to use `{}` to add value to string

```
url = 'https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/?page={}'.format(i+1)
```

or concatenate it

```
url = 'https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/?page=' + str(i+1)
```

or use `f-string`

```
url = f'https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/?page={i+1}'
```

---

**EDIT:** working code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # HTML data structure
import pandas as pd

def get_page_data(number):
    print('number:', number)
    
    url = 'https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/?page={}'.format(number)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    container = soup.find(id='nav-lista-obiektow')
    items = container.find_all(class_='et-list__details flex-grow-1 d-flex d-md-block flex-column')

    # better group them - so you could add default value if there is no nazwa or adres
    dane = []
    
    for item in items:
        nazwa = item.find(class_='h3 et-list__details__name').get_text(strip=True)
        adres = item.find(class_='et-list__city').get_text(strip=True)
        dane.append([nazwa, adres])
        
    return dane

# --- main ---

wszystkie_dane = []
for number in range(1, 23):
    dane_na_stronie = get_page_data(number)
    wszystkie_dane.extend(dane_na_stronie)

dane = pd.DataFrame(wszystkie_dane, columns=['nazwa', 'adres'])

dane.to_csv('noclegi.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I added working exampl (PL: dodałem działący przykład)

Comment: Thank you! And great idea with data grouping!

Answer (score 1):

in your loop you use the `.format()` function but need to insert the brackets into the string you are formatting.

```
for i in range(22):
    url = requests.get('https://e-turysta.pl/noclegi-krakow/{}'.format(i+1)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
```